# Using vanilla javascript to hide a tag that contains certain text

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have this code that hides a div that only contains a specific word, I've been trying (with no luck) to hide any div that contains this word, but also contains more text.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
    let div = divs[x];
    let content = div.innerHTML.trim();
  
    if (content == 'example') {
       div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    ipsum
</div>
<div class="test">
    example
</div>
<div class="test">
    example complete
</div>
```

Comment: Your example works tho, what's the problem?

Comment: Could be that you put your js code before the dom render? try `window.onload` to call the functions.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy it works for exact matches (as seen in the code sample - `example` is hidden) but not any content that includes the term (also seen in the snippet - `example complete` is not hidden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Something modern…**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach((element, index) => {
   if (element.innerText.includes('example')) {
       element.style.display = 'none';
   }
})
```

```html
<div class="test">ipsum</div>
<div class="test">example</div>
<div class="test">example complete</div>
```

**Docs:**
[NodeList.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)
[String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: ha! now that's exactly what I would have done, nice :) Oh.. well maybe I'd use an arrow function :P

Comment: Do I misunderstood something ? @Andy

Comment: @Andy Hmmm.. why he accepted me?. I think we are not sure what he need :)

Comment: @user2965583 This is what you need? check result

Comment: @Andy, I think he needs something like this. Please de-downvoted me

Answer (score 5):

You could use JavaScript's [`string.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

A hacky way to only remove the div containing *more then* only "examaple" is to have `"example "` in the `includes()`. This will only remove the div if the innerHTML has a space after "example"

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
    let div = divs[x];
    let content = div.innerHTML.trim();
  
    if (content.includes('example')) {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    ipsum
</div>
<div class="test">
    example
</div>
<div class="test">
    example complete
</div>
```

Comment: I think, that's exactly whats the op want.

Comment: `contains this word, but also contains more text.`

Comment: exactly tresf, I need also to hide the div that contains the text: "example complete" . With my current code, I can only hide the div that contains the text:"example".

Comment: @MartijnVissers I'd just do: `if(divs[x].innerHTML.includes('example')`  but anyways :D

Comment: @Elias There are lots of ways to shorten this code, but idk if OP has any more code that isn't needed for the question or something so a small change might be best. But thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @MartijnVissers Sure thing... I actually like your answer more :)

Comment: @MartijnVissers This would be my [goto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54310417/10315665).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the div that contains the search word (checked with [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)) but that also has other characters in it perhaps store the word in a variable and check to see if the text is longer than that.

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
const word = 'example';

for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
  let div = divs[x];
  let content = div.innerHTML.trim();
  if (content.includes(word) & content.length > word.length) {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
ipsum
</div>
<div class="test">
example
</div>
<div class="test">
example complete
</div>
```

Here's a modernised version of that code.

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
const word = 'example';

divs.forEach(div => {
  const { style, textContent } = div;
  const trimmed = textContent.trim();
  if (trimmed.includes(word) && trimmed.length > word.length) {
    style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="test">
ipsum
</div>
<div class="test">
example
</div>
<div class="test">
example complete
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `div.innerHTML.trim()`, it takes the entirety of the div element.

https://jsfiddle.net/ucvteLq7/7/

Try to search around regular expressions, and I think, you shouldn't hide a div according its class, but you must replace what it contains. Sorry that I can't help more.